# Jackson Serialize Circular References Stack overflow Error

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, overflowexception

I am trying to serialise my POJO which looks as follows using Jackson Object mapper, I get stack over flow exception, please help on this. Thanks in advance

```
public class ServiceCategoryModel {

    private Integer svcCode;

    private String svcName;

    @JsonBackReference
    private Collection<ServiceCategoryModel> children;
....
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have got a bean with one of the references in `children` pointing to the same bean object.

Comment: @DarshanMehta - Yes Darshan you got me the right direction thanks

Comment: @TheHeadRush - Above link is the one exactly i want, i resolved the problem after making changes as follows. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its works after I make changes as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="svc_category")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class ServiceCategoryDomain extends BaseDomain{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5873300401604877065L;

    @Column(name="svc_cde")
    @NotNull
    private Integer svcCode;

    @Column(name="svc_name")
    @NotNull
    private String svcName;

    @JsonBackReference("parent")
    @ManyToOne
    private ServiceCategoryDomain parent;

    @JsonManagedReference("children")
    @OneToMany (cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy="parent")
    private Collection<ServiceCategoryDomain> children=new ArrayList<>();
    ..................
}
```